# Access database on network

Tags: c#-4.0, setup-deployment

I made a small C# Winform application with a simple GUI and a database (MyDB). Now I want to run my application on the Server.  I want other users to access my database through the network. I have a Wired\Wireless network.

Suppose I have 2 systems (sys1, sys2) I have my application in sys1. I created a shortcut of my application in sys1 and tried to run that shortcut. It worked.

But when I am trying to open the shortcut in sys2, it gave me error:

> "The drive or network connection that the shortcut 'application.lnk'
>   refers to is unavailable. Make sure the disk is properly inserted or
>   network resource is available, and then try again.".

Then I copied my `application.exe.config` file near `application.lnk`.

Do I change anything in ConnectionString?  What causes this error?

Note: Application made in C# 4.0, VS 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like on sys1, application.lnk is pointing to your local copy, such as `C:\MyApp\App.exe`.  When you copy application.lnk over to sys2, it's trying to find a file called C:\MyApp.App.exe on that machine, which doesn't exist.

You'll have to host your application on a network drive, such as `\\MyServer\Apps\App.exe` and create a shortcut to that instead.  That link should then work on any computer with access to that share.

Comment: can you extend your help further. I mean how to create this server kind of thing. I have Windows 7 on both the systems. I have no idea, how to proceed. Thanks

Comment: You're gonna want to do some basic research, this subject is rather broad for a specific answer here.  A good place to start is: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/File-sharing-essentials